# POSTFIX/sendmail suddenly adding extra line breaks

Tags: php, email, sendmail, postfix-mta, line-endings

Over the weekend our MTA (POSTFIX) suddenly started prepending line breaks to the boundaries of our messages.
We have several PHP templates that define multipart/alternative messages and define the headers.
Here is the PHP mailer format, which was working friday, then just suddenly stopped on monday.

```
$headers = "From: name <our@example.com>\r\n" .
   "Reply-To: name <our@example.com>\r\n" .
   "MIME-Version: 1.0\r\n" .
   "Content-Type: multipart/alternative; boundary=\"09127kjhd821\"";

$txt = "\r\n\r\n--09127kjhd821\r\n" .
   "Content-Type: text/plain; charset=UTF-8\r\n" .
   "Content-Transfer-Encoding: quoted-printable\r\n\r\n" .
   "Text Message";

$html = "\r\n\r\n--09127kjhd821\r\n".
   "Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8\r\n" .
   "Content-Transfer-Encoding: base64\r\n\r\n" .
   chunk_split( base64_encode( "HTML Message") );

$body = $txt . $html . "\r\n\r\n--09127kjhd821--";

mail(
   "someone@example.com",
   "=?UTF-8?B?" . base64_encode( "Subject" ) . "?=",
   $body,
   $headers
);
```

Comparing the original mails to the broken ones i see the following
Broken:

```
Date: Fri,  3 Aug 2012 16:52:39 -0400 (EDT)





--09127kjhd821

Content-Type: text/plain; charset=UTF-8

Content-Transfer-Encoding: quoted-printable
```

Original (Working)

```
Date: Tue, 31 Jul 2012 12:36:45 -0400 (EDT)



--09127kjhd821
Content-Type: text/plain; charset=UTF-8
Content-Transfer-Encoding: quoted-printable
```

As you can see the line breaks are off pretty much doubling for each \r and \n, nothing was changed to my knowledge that would cause this.

Any suggestions or help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: first, Did you use the same version of the same mail client to view both of these messages?

Comment: We have multiple clients complaining. The kicker is that our gmail seems to display them fine, as does hotmail and my phone. While other gmail clients see the MIME format. I am using one of our clients inbox to view the messages and have talked to their server admin to see if it may have been caused by a spam filter post processing the message, and then we began to receive complaints from others as well. *EDIT* Also I posted the email source file body, not the client parsed body.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The only thing I can come up with is the POSTFIX and PHP issues with converting LF to CRLF so when CRLF is defined in the message body for boundaries and headers it is being converted to CRCRLF.
Saving the message source however only displays as CRLF in the hex editor though, which may be a conversion in the editor I use or email client download process.

I still don't understand why it just suddenly changed as it was working fine previously.
The only difference I can think of is maybe due to the scripts line-endings that may have changed from CRLF to LF causing a conversion to take place and thus breaking emails that contain CRLF in the body.

I ultimately fixed the issue by changing the sendmail_path in php.ini to

```
sendmail_path="/usr/bin/dos2unix|/usr/sbin/sendmail -t -i"
```

Comment: I actually determined the issue. Our firewall has an email filter, which apparently was editing the body of the message and properly formatting it. So the issue above was being fixed by our firewall's email filter. The email filter subscription expired the day in question, causing all of our emails being sent to be malformed.